# How to sum interfaces in a variable definition in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, types, interface

Say we have got 2 interfaces: `IOne` and `ITwo` and I want to define a function that accepts arguments of any type that implements both of these interfaces at the same time. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an interface that both `ITwo` and `IOne` inherit from it.

```
public void SomeFunction(INumber argument)
{         
} 
public interface INumber
{
} 
public interface ITwo : INumber
{
}
public interface IOne : INumber
{
}
```

or use Generic:

```
public void SomeFunction<T>(T argument) where T : IOne, ITwo
{   
}
```

Comment: Your first solution does not guarantee that `argument` implements both interfaces at the same time. In fact, it may not implement either one of them! Your second solution is good, though :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
interface IOne {void Hello();}
interface ITwo {void World();}

static void Foo<T>(T arg) where T : IOne, ITwo {
    arg.Hello();
    arg.World();
}
```